# Error when using wget to download a list of URLs in a .txt file

Tags: command-line, 64-bit, wget

My question is about downloading a list of URLs using `wget`. The URLs are listed in a text file named `url-list.txt`, which I have saved on my desktop. Whereas I'm using the bionic distro, on a 64-bit computer, I get the error message `url-list.txt: No such file or directory. No urls found in url-list.txt`

I've used this command in the terminal:

```
wget -i url-list.txt
```

Could it be that I've used the wrong syntax while writing the URLs? I simply copied the URLs from my browser and pasted them into the `url-list.txt` file prior to saving the file.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: "No such file or directory" does NOT mean a Syntax Error. It means you are looking for the file in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a bit misleading.

`wget` shows this message if it can't find the file.

Please double check your path to the file and the file name.

You could also try a `ls !$` directly after your failed wget command - this expands to `ls url-list.txt` and you will see it is not a wget issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the path to the file and the file name. It finally worked.